# Add button in a react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap-table (`var ReactBsTable = require("react-bootstrap-table")`).

I want to add a column that just contain a button in a bootstraptable .

Any idea thanks.

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.activities} pagination={true} hover={true} search={true} selectRow={selectRowProp} options={options}>
  <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField="id" hidden {true}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort={true}>Title</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="adress" dataSort{true}>Adress</TableHeaderColumn>
  ///I dont know if here or there is option to use
 </BootstrapTable>
```

I tried to add a button which display the id or the row data correspondent to this button.
I used jquery but I give an id to the button but all these buttons would have the same id so just the first one work and the rest no.

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.activities} pagination={true} hover={true} search={true} selectRow={selectRowProp} options={options}>
  <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField="id" hidden {true}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="title" dataSort={true}>Title</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="adress" dataSort{true}>Adress</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="button" dataFormat={this.buttonFunction}></TableHeaderColumn>

 </BootstrapTable>

buttonFunction: function (cell, row) {
        var today = new Date().toISOString();
        if (row.status === "En cours") {
            if (row.dateEnd > today) {
                return <Alert_Validate></Alert_Validate>;
            } else {
                return <label>
                    <button type="button" id="validatebutton" onClick={this._validateFunction} className="bbtn btn-primary btn-sm"><i className="fa fa-check fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </label>

            }
        }
    },

_validateFunction: function () {
        var userid=this.props.params.id;
        $("#validatebutton").click(function() {
            var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
             var activityid = $row.find("td:nth-child(2)");
            console.log("activity id :"+activityid.text());
        });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can make a new function `buttonFormatter` to add button to every cell of the column

```
// products will be presented by react-bootstrap-table
var products = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Item name 1",
  price: 100
},{
  id: 2,
  name: "Item name 2",
  price: 100
},........];

// It's a data format example.
function priceFormatter(cell, row){
  return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></i> ' + cell;
},
function buttonFormatter(cell, row){
  return '<BootstrapButton type="submit"></BootstrapButton>';
}

React.render(
  <BootstrapTable data={products} striped={true} hover={true}>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" dataSort={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" dataSort={true}>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price" dataFormat={priceFormatter}>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="button" dataFormat={buttonFormatter}>Buttons</TableHeaderColumn>
  </BootstrapTable>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well my question. I need the button inside the column for each row and not in the header.

Comment: I need to get the cell or row when i click on the button .Is there any idea?

Comment: Please explain the architecture that you want to build? Where do you want to access your `cell` and `row`? You can access them in the `buttonFormatter` method already. Try putting some logic in the same function. Anyway, i'd suggest you use `react-bootstrap` as it is quite simple and its documentation is really nice. You can import only `table` from `react-bootstrap`, so size of the app wont be the issue.

Comment: @iamsaksham I have a similar issue, I would like to display the button conditionally. I'm trying to compare the `ids` of the objects in my database and compare them to the `row.id`. depending on the result I would like to display a different button. Can you please have a look at my SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244914/how-to-conditionally-render-the-button-in-react-bootstrap-table-the-button-fo

Comment: any idea on how to archieve this on react-boostrap-table2 ?

Comment: @Gutimore Hi, I haven't explored react-bootstrap-table2 yet, let me explore it and I'll update my answer soon

Comment: @Gultimore Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553682/adding-edit-button-with-icon-in-a-react-bootstrap-table2

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar situation, I was implemented this code, I hope it helps you.

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/63821/

```
var dataFake = [
{
  name: 'Product 1',
  priceUnit: 23.50
},
{
  name: 'Product 2',
  priceUnit: 24.50
},
{
  name: 'Product 3',
  priceUnit: 33.20
}];


class Products extends React.Component {
  onClickProductSelected(cell, row, rowIndex){
   console.log('Product #', rowIndex);
  }

  cellButton(cell, row, enumObject, rowIndex) {
    return (
       <button 
          type="button" 
          onClick={() => 
          this.onClickProductSelected(cell, row, rowIndex)}
       >
       Click me { rowIndex }
       </button>
    )
 }

 render() {
   return (
    <BootstrapTable data={this.props.data}>
     <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' isKey>
        Name
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='priceUnit'>
        Price
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn
        dataField='button'
        dataFormat={this.cellButton.bind(this)}
      />
   </BootstrapTable>
  )
 }
}



ReactDOM.render(
   <Products data={dataFake} />,
   document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, I would like to display the button conditionally. I'm trying to compare the `ids` of the objects in my database and compare them to the `row.id`. depending on the result I would like to display a different button. Can you please have a look at my SO question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244914/how-to-conditionally-render-the-button-in-react-bootstrap-table-the-button-fo

Comment: This helped me work out the 'this' binding to be able to call another function from within the button renderer for the dataFormat. Thanks for the example!