# Adding Edit button with icon in a react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a column like this in the table to edit the whole **corresponding row** *corresponding to each edit button* in react-Bootstrap_**table2**

Sample Image of What I want to do:

[image: 1]

```js
import React from "react";
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
import cellEditFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-editor";

export class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [
        {
          id: 1,
          dn: "Gob",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "2",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          dn: "Buster",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "5",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          dn: "Gob",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "2",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          dn: "Buster",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "5",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          dn: "George Michael",
          f: "wah",
          ct: "4",
          cr: "acha",
          dsf: 12,
          dsp: 30
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        {
          dataField: "dn",
          text: "Doctor Name",
          sort: true
        },
        {
          dataField: "f",
          text: "Facility",
          sort: true
        },
        {
          dataField: "ct",
          text: "Consultation Type",
          sort: true
        },
        {
          dataField: "cr",
          text: "Consultation Rate",
          sort: true
        },
        {
          dataField: "dsf",
          text: "Doctor Share (Fixed)",
          sort: true,
          style: { backgroundColor: "#e0f7fa" }
        },
        {
          dataField: "dsp",
          text: "Doctor Share(%)",
          sort: true,
          style: { backgroundColor: "#fbe9e7" }
        },
        {
          dataField: "edit",
          text: "Edit",
          editCellStyle: (cell, row, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
            const icon = { style: 'class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">' };
            return { icon };
          }
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    const selectRow = {
      mode: "checkbox",
      clickToSelect: true
    };

    // const editFormatter = (cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) => {
    //   <Button
    //     icon
    //     labelPosition="left"
    //     onClick={() => deleteMe(rowIndex, rowId)}
    //   >
    //     <Icon name="remove" /> Remove{" "}
    //   </Button>;
    // };
    const customTotal = (from, to, size) => (
      <span className="react-bootstrap-table-pagination-total">
        Showing {from} to {to} of {size} Results
      </span>
    );

    return (
      <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>
        <BootstrapTable
          striped
          hover
          keyField="dn"
          data={this.state.data}
          columns={this.state.columns}
          pagination={paginationFactory({ nextPageText: "Next" })}
          selectRow={selectRow}
          cellEdit={cellEditFactory({ mode: "click" })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I add buttons in the column of **Edit** ?
so that I should be able to edit a row.
I know there must be some mechanism to customize the column and add
Icons like mentioned in the Image.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO. You need to share the code so that we can be able to help you with the solution

Comment: @Think-Twice re-edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this function and returned the EditIcon button component.

```
function rankFormatter(cell, row, rowIndex, formatExtraData) { 
     return ( 
           < div 
               style={{ textAlign: "center",
                  cursor: "pointer",
                 lineHeight: "normal" }}>

        < EditIcon
          style={{ fontSize: 20 }}
          color="disabled"  
         /> 
      </div> 
 ); }
```

This is the column where I have assigned the rankFormatter function to the formatter.

```
      { dataField: "edit", 
        text: "Edit",
        sort: false,
        formatter: rankFormatter,
        headerAttrs: { width: 50 },
        attrs: { width: 50, class: "EditRow" } 
      }
```

This works exactly the way I wanted it to be..!

Comment: can you share the complete code please

Comment: @dude_blag Here is the sandbox link I have created for you. It has all the working code.
  https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-varahamihira-h9w2vu?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: thanks mate, I'd figured it out :)

Answer (score 10):

You can add a dummy field in your column definitions and reference a formatter that can render a component in the column for each row.  The component, in our case, is an ActionsFormater that we use to render several buttons (view,edit,delete) that can act on the id passed in for each row.

```
{
    dataField: 'actions',
    text: 'Actions',
    isDummyField: true,
    csvExport: false,
    formatter: this.actionsFormatter,
  },

actionsFormatter = (cell, row) => <ActionsFormatter id={row.id} />;
```

Which looks like so:

[image: react-bootstrap-table2 with buttons in column]

Comment: where did you exactly gave the icons for the button? and where is the button tag given?

Comment: Ok I made a component of edit button and then imported that component as ActionsFormatter. But the className ="any Glyphicon" is not working in a button tag in the ActionsFormatter Component

Comment: That is specific to your tools.  We are using Font Awesome and react-strap and a button looks like this:                                                                               
    <Button title="Edit" size="sm" color="info">
      <span className="fa fa-pencil" />
    </Button>

Answer (score 1):

the solutions from the other users work, but I just noticed that the current version of reactstrap-table-next has built-in support for this so I will this answer for future users.

It's possible to show an extra column by setting the property `expandRow.showExpandColumn` to true.
Then to expand rows only when clicking this column the property `expandRow.expandByColumnOnly` must be set to true as well.
The side where this column appears can be set through the property `expandRow.expandByColumnOnly` whose value can either be `left` or `right`

Finally we must also pass a renderer for this column through the property 'expandRow.expandColumnRenderer' which takes a function like this  `({ expanded, rowKey, expandable }) => ()`

expandRow example :

```
const expandRow = {
    renderer: row => ...,
    expandByColumnOnly: true,
    expandColumnPosition: 'right',
    showExpandColumn: true,
    expandColumnRenderer: ({expanded, rowKey, expandable}) => {
        const onclick = (event) => {
            console.log("clicked on row ", rowKey)
        }

        if (!expandable) {
            return;
        }
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={onclick} className="btn btn-outline-primary"/>
        );
    }
};

...

<BootstrapTable ... expandRow={expandRow} />
```

[Documentation here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/row-expand-props.html#expandrowrenderer-function)